# Скрипт для выбора диапазона с логарифмической шкалой

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Подскажите готовый JS скрипт с выбором диапазона и логарифмической шкалой.

Например, как сотмаркете в выборке по цене [www.sotmarket.ru/category/bolgarki.html](http://www.sotmarket.ru/category/bolgarki.html)

[Что такое логарифмическая шкала](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Comment: jquery-iu: [slider][1]


  [1]: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Comment: ну слайдер можно простилизовать + абсолютом рядом кинуть шкалу

Comment: @Денис Шамко, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Как пример: http://jsfiddle.net/7uzaR/

```
var steps = [0, 1, 3, 6, 12, 20];

$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ 0, 500 ],
    "step": 25,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var step1 = ui.values[ 0 ]/25;
        var step2 = ui.values[ 1 ]/25;

        if(steps.indexOf(step1)===-1 || steps.indexOf(step2)===-1) return false;

        $( "#amount" ).text( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }
});
```

Comment: это обычная шкала, линейная. надо наоборот step фиксированный, а value - какая-то экспонента.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov м? http://jsfiddle.net/7uzaR/1/

Comment: угу, что-то типа того. использовать массив или нет зависит от задачи, в принципе можно экспонентой таки обойтись, особенно если числа всегда разные.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov ну я сначала и хотел что-то типа какой-то функции применять, но потом посмотрел, как выглядит шкала, подумал о другом.

Answer (score 0):

Мой выбор: $.noUiSlider

http://refreshless.com/nouislider/